# Query ContentItems in Orchard

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I have a list of 'Article' content items. On this article is an article part, which has a field I'd like to reference in my query.

`_contentManager.Query("Article").Where<ArticlePartRecord>(o => o.MyField == "criteria");`

The above would work, but I don't have the strongly typed `ArticlePartRecord` to pass into the `Where`.

How else can I achieve this?

**What I've Tried**

I've tried iterating through the parts and fields within the `Where`, but this would then be done for every single article, of which there could be thousands. It'd pose a few performance problems.

Must I create the type? Or can I pass a string or work around it somehow? If it's a case of creating the class, what fields should this have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long and short is that you cant query fields really. Can you move the field into the Article part?

Do you need to be querying or can you use a Projection? There you can query fields because it indexes them all. I suppose you could try to search that index, though I don't believe it exposes it in a very friendly way, but I'm not 100% on that.